# Easiest way to label and count string occurrences in freeform text in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Given these two R dataframes of a set of freeform texts and a set of arbitrary keywords:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c(
"I have a social media account on Twitter",
"I love cheese recipes on Facebook",
"I love cheese recipes on Pinterest",
"I am a social media marketer on Instagram who loves social media",
"I love posting cheese recipes on social media",
"Conspiracy theories are logical fallacies"
)) |>
rename(phrase = 1)

keyword_df <- as.data.frame(c(
"social media",
"cheese recipe",
"tinfoil hat"
))
```

What's the easiest tidyverse way to create this outcome?

| phrase | social_media | cheese_recipe | tinfoil_hat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I have a social media account on Twitter | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| I love cheese recipes on Facebook | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| I love cheese recipes on Pinterest | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| I am a social media marketer on Instagram who loves social media | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| I love posting cheese recipes on social media | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Conspiracy theories are logical fallacies | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df %>%
  mutate(as.data.frame(lapply(
    setNames(nm = keyword_df[[1]]),
    function(z) lengths(stringr::str_extract_all(phrase, z))
  )))
#                                                             phrase social.media cheese.recipe tinfoil.hat
# 1                         I have a social media account on Twitter            1             0           0
# 2                                I love cheese recipes on Facebook            0             1           0
# 3                               I love cheese recipes on Pinterest            0             1           0
# 4 I am a social media marketer on Instagram who loves social media            2             0           0
# 5                    I love posting cheese recipes on social media            1             1           0
# 6                        Conspiracy theories are logical fallacies            0             0           0
```